# Spring form validator with multiple buttons

Tags: html, forms, spring

I'm developing a project using Spring 3.0.

I have a form with several submit buttons.

What I would like to do is to have different validation requirements depending on the pressed button.

How do I do this? An example would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple implementation of Spring [Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html). And depending on the button clicked you can call validate method of required validator implementation from controller.
Here is a [example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) of validation using spring validator.

Comment: Yes that would be a way to go but that would mean that if I had 3 buttons I would need to have 3 validator classes... right? :(

Comment: @RedEagle: Yes OR you can keep different conditions in validator and pass some parameter to validator which reflects which button is clicked.

Comment: Thats the way to go... I've added a enumerator to control the pressed button

Comment: @RedEagle: I think that will serve the purpose.